# Printf() prints string arguments out of order

Tags: c, printf

I have some C-code that reads in a text file line by line, hashes the strings in each line, and keeps a running count of the string with the biggest hash values.

It seems to be doing the right thing but when I issue the print statement:

```
 printf("Found Bigger Hash:%s\tSize:%d\n", textFile.biggestHash, textFile.maxASCIIHash);
```

my print returns this in the output:

Preprocessing: dict1
Found BiSize:110h:a
Found BiSize:857h:aardvark
Found BiSize:861h:aardwolf
Found BiSize:937h:abandoned
Found BiSize:951h:abandoner
Found BiSize:1172:abandonment
Found BiSize:1283:abbreviation
Found BiSize:1364:abiogenetical
Found BiSize:1593:abiogenetically
Found BiSize:1716:absentmindedness
Found BiSize:1726:acanthopterygian
Found BiSize:1826:accommodativeness
Found BiSize:1932:adenocarcinomatous
Found BiSize:2162:adrenocorticotrophic
Found BiSize:2173:chemoautotrophically
Found BiSize:2224:counterrevolutionary
Found BiSize:2228:counterrevolutionist
Found BiSize:2258:dendrochronologically
Found BiSize:2440:electroencephalographic
Found BiSize:4893:pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
Biggest  Size:46umonoultTotal Words:71885covolcanoconiosis

So tt seems I'm misusing printf(). Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_LENGTH 100 // Max number of characters per word

// data1 struct carries information about the dictionary file; preprocess() initializes it
struct data1
{
   int numRows; 
   int maxWordSize; 
   char* biggestWord;
   int maxASCIIHash; 
   char* biggestHash;  
}; 

int asciiHash(char* wordToHash); 
struct data1 preprocess(char* fileName); 


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   //Diagnostics Purposes; Not used for algorithm  
   printf("Preprocessing: %s\n",argv[1]); 
   struct data1 file = preprocess(argv[1]); 
   printf("Biggest Word:%s\t Size:%d\tTotal Words:%d\n", file.biggestWord, file.maxWordSize, file.numRows);  
   //printf("Biggest hashed word (by ASCII sum):%s\tSize: %d\n", file.biggestHash, file.maxASCIIHash);  
   //printf("**%s**", file.biggestHash); 
   return 0; 
}

int asciiHash(char* word)
{
   int runningSum = 0; 
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<strlen(word); i++)
   {
      runningSum += *(word+i); 
   }
   return runningSum; 
}

struct data1 preprocess(char* fName)
{
   static struct data1 textFile = {.numRows = 0, .maxWordSize = 0, .maxASCIIHash = 0};
   textFile.biggestWord = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH*sizeof(char));    
   textFile.biggestHash = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH*sizeof(char));  
   char* str = (char*) malloc(WORD_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); 

   FILE* fp = fopen(fName, "r"); 
   while( strtok(fgets(str, WORD_LENGTH, fp), "\n") != NULL)
   {
      // If found a larger hash
      int hashed = asciiHash(str);
      if(hashed > textFile.maxASCIIHash)
      { 
         textFile.maxASCIIHash = hashed;  // Update max hash size found
         strcpy(textFile.biggestHash, str); // Update biggest hash string
         printf("Found Bigger Hash:%s\tSize:%d\n", textFile.biggestHash, textFile.maxASCIIHash);   
      }
      // If found a larger word
      if( strlen(str) > textFile.maxWordSize)
      {
         textFile.maxWordSize = strlen(str); // Update biggest word size
         strcpy(textFile.biggestWord, str); // Update biggest word 
      }
      textFile.numRows++; 
   }

   fclose(fp); 
   free(str); 
   return textFile; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your strings, not printf. E.g. carriage returns (`'\r'`) can mess up your text display.

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and inspect it with a hex editor for weird characters.

Comment: Please read and respond to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're right, melpomene!

Comment: Jongware, I've never debugged it that way. Do you use the redirection operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to remove the `\r` after reading. This is in your input because (1) your source file comes from a Windows machine (or at least one which uses `\r\n` line endings), and (2) you use the `fopen` mode `"r"`, which does not translate line endings on your OS (again, presumably Windows).

This results in the weird output as follows:

```
Found Bigger Hash:text\r\tSize:123
```

– see the position of the `\r`? So what happens when *outputting* this string, you get at first

```
Found Bigger Hash:text
```

and then the cursor gets repositioned to the start of the line by `\r`. Next, a tab is output – not by printing spaces but merely moving the cursor to the 8thth position:

```
1234567↓
Found Bigger Hash:text
```

and the rest of the string is printed over the one already shown:

```
Found BiSize:123h:text
```

Possible solutions:

1. Open your file in `"rt"` "text" mode, and/or
2. Check for, and remove, the `\r` code as well as `\n`.

I'd go for both. `strchr` is pretty cheap and will make your code a bit more foolproof.

(Also, please simplify your `fgets` line by splitting it up into several distinct operations.)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
while( strtok(fgets(str, WORD_LENGTH, fp), "\n") != NULL)
```

takes no account of the return value from `fgets()` or the way `strtok()` works.

The way to do this is something like

```
char *fptr, *sptr;
while ((fptr = fgets(str, WORD_LENGTH, fp)) != NULL) {
    sptr = strtok(fptr, "\n");
    while (sptr != NULL) {
        printf ("%s,", sptr);
        sptr = strtok (NULL, "\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note than after the first call to `strtok()`, subsequent calls on the same sequence must pass the parameter `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The input file actually consists of many lines on which a word and a newline character (or so I thought) appears so there isn't a need to call strtok(NULL) multiple times.

Comment: Hence, I think it's ok to nest strtok(fgets()).

Comment: I almost deleted this answer earlier because it's evident you use `strtok` to remove the line endings. Point 1. use `strtok(..., "\r\n")` to cover all types of line ending. Point 2, what will happen when the file has no data and you pass `NULL` from `fgets()` to `strtok()` on the very first call? My advice stands: it is better to analyse the function values independently.

Comment: strtok(NULL,"\n") returns NULL if there are no tokens to retrieve (which would be the case if you pass strtok() NULL). So it is ok (although unsightly) if fgets() returns NULL.

Comment: @MinhTran no, when I pass `NULL` as the first argument to `strtok()` on its first call, the system hangs, because it's internal state has not been initialised. You can only pass `NULL` on *subsequent* calls to analyse the string originally passed.

Comment: Ah ok. I did not know that! Is it bad that the "system hangs"? (I'm not sure what you mean).

Comment: By "the system hangs" I mean there is a pause and then the pop-up "test.exe has stopped working. Windows is looking for a solution to this problem."

Comment: Woah! I see. I was running on cloud9, evidently a programming environment where they let bad programming slide. 
Anyways, I will take your advice to heart. Thanks again :)

Comment: By the way, how come you didn't malloc() for fptr,sptr?

Comment: @MinhTran I didn't `malloc` for `fptr` or `sptr` because they are pointers to already allocated memory `str`